# does domcontentloaded wait for other scripts to finish loading?

Tags: javascript, html

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello world
    <script>
       print();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/static/js/index.js"></script>
           
</body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
function print(){
   console.log('Hello, world!')
}
```

**Uncaught ReferenceError: print is not defined** It gives me such error because index.js is not arrived yet. I could do it in this way

```
//
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/static/js/index.js"></script>
<script>
  print();
</script>
//
```

But in my real case I can't do that. I tried to do in this way:

```
//
 <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        print();
    })
 </script>
//
```

Does DOMContentLoaded event waits for all js files to arrive?

Comment: The solution here is to (a) not use inline scripts, write your JS in .js files and load those like everything else, never use bare `<script>` tags with JS directly on the page, and (b) loading your scripts with `<script src="..." async defer></script>` so that they get loaded without blocking the page, and get executed only once the page has been parsed. There hasn't been a need to use a `DOMContentLoaded` event listener since IE11 came out in late 2013 (and note that the `async` and `defer` attributes means you can put everything in the `<head>`, no need for 2012 style "end of `<body>`")

Comment: Or just move your script library references to just before the closing `body` tag.